# vector loop not reaching all elements

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I have the following piece of code that takes in some words, stores them into a vector, sorts them, then counts how many times each word appears and outputs it:

```
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
vector<string> words;

string c;

cout << "Enter some words!" << endl << endl;
while (cin >> c) {
    words.push_back(c);
}

vec_sz size = words.size();
sort(words.begin(), words.end());

string current_word = words[0];
int count = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (words[i] == current_word) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The word " + current_word + " appears " << count << " times." << endl;
        current_word = words[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}
```

I enter some words:

```
word
word
lol
hello
lol
word
hello
^Z
```

I then get the following output:

```
The word hello appears 2 times.
The word lol appears 2 times.
```

But it never reaches the final set of words. I changed my loop to just print out each element in the vector and it does print out all of them. But for some reason this loop does not want to reach the final set of words. What is going wrong?

Comment: Why not use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)?

Comment: I am doing exercises from the book I am learning from, so I would like to stay within what I have learned so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last word is being reached, here:

```
else {
    // Previous word printed
    cout << "The word " + current_word + " appears " << count << " times." << endl;
    // current_word set to last word
    current_word = words[i];
    count = 1;
}
```

And then the loop exits. So, you would need a final line outside the loop to print the last word and its count.

Answer (score 2):

The count message is only printed when a different word is found. When the last word is found, a different word is not encountered so a message is not printed. You need a piece of code after the `for` to print out the count for last word.

There are other ways to achieve this, using a `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>` for example:

```
map<string, unsigned int> word_counts;
string c;

cout << "Enter some words!" << endl << endl;
while (cin >> c) {
    word_counts[c]++;
}

for (map<string, unsigned int>::iterator wci = word_counts.begin();
     wci != word_counts.end();
     wci++)
{
    cout << "The word " << wci->first << " appears " << wci->second << "times.";
}
```